# How to update d3.js svg with nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938500/accessing-nested-json-structure-in-d3) but I need to draw svg elements rather than create a list.

I want to be able to visualize nested data where 1-many objects serve as containers holding 1 to many objects.
For example:

```
cars = [
        {
        type:
        parkingSpot:
        passengers = 
            [ {role: } ]
        }
]
```

I would like for the user to be able to add a car by clicking a button, and have one passenger automatically created with the role of driver.

I understand how to add a new car, but I can't figure out how to make a driver appear in each car. Here is what I have so far:

```
function addCar() {
    cars.push(new car(parkingSpot));
    svg.selectAll("car").data(cars).enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return parkingSpot * 150;
        })
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("height", 300)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("class", "car")

    svg.selectAll("passenger").data(???????).enter()
        .append("circle")
                .attr( ... )
                .attr("class", "passenger");

parkingSpot++;
}
```

What I have tried either doesn't work, or ends up stacking a new set of passenger circles for each car that is made.

I want to be able to go back and add more passengers in the future, in which case the old passengers may need to move around.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5DMe/10/ (doesn't seem to work, could be my browser)

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IegGb (does work)

Comment: It would be just `.data(cars)` again and then select the nested passenger, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lars suggested,

```
.data(cars)
```

would cause a new circle to be drawn in each car every time the addCar function was called.

I found that by using:

```
.data(cars[cars.length - 1].passengers)
```

to only select the newest car, I was able to draw only the newest circle.