# Nested JSON not working in d3.js

Tags: json, d3.js

I am using nested JSON file in my data visualization using d3.js. I was referring to a previous [Smilar Queastion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938500/accessing-nested-json-structure-in-d3). I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbf1u640/) of the answer of the question to see whether things are working. But i am confused why the code is not working. I have similar type of problem in my project. How can i solve that. Here is sample code I am using for printing the data in the form of a list

```
d3.select("body").append("ul").selectAll("li")
.data(data).enter().append("li").each(function() {
  var li = d3.select(this);
  li.append("p")
      .text(function(d) { return d.date; });
  li.append("ul").selectAll("li")
      .data(function(d) { return d.hours; }) // second level data-join
    .enter().append("li")
      .text(function(d) { return d.hour + ": " + d.hits; });
});
```

Comment: Solved. Replace outside second brackets with third brackets. Then it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the JSON wasn't formed correctly.  I fixed the JSON like this -

```
    var data=[{ "date": "20120927", 
  "hours": [
           { "hour": 0, "hits": 823896 }, 
           { "hour": 1, "hits": 654335 }, 
           { "hour": 2, "hits": 548812 }, 
           { "hour": 3, "hits": 512863 }, 
           { "hour": 4, "hits": 500639 }
           ],
  "totalHits": "32,870,234", 
  "maxHits": "2,119,767", 
  "maxHour": 12, 
  "minHits": "553,821", 
  "minHour": 3 },
{ "date": "20120928", 
  "hours": [ 
           { "hour": 0, "hits": 1235923 }, 
           { "hour": 1, "hits": 654335 }, 
           { "hour": 2, "hits": 1103849 }, 
           { "hour": 3, "hits": 512863 }, 
           { "hour": 4, "hits": 488506 }
           ],
  "totalHits": "32,870,234", 
  "maxHits": "2,119,767", 
  "maxHour": 12, 
  "minHits": "553,821", 
      "minHour": 3 }];
```

Also, I think there was a problem with the HTTP d3.js library not being loaded.  I added an external HTTPS reference and it is working.

Here is a working version of your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ferlin_husky/wzuvob6m/

Comment: What is the error in my json. Doesn't  it take double quotations?

Comment: Yap got it. I need to add external resource instead thanks. My code is working with double quotations also. Here is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pbf1u640/6/

Comment: Double quotes are ok.  I updated my answer so it was more clear.

Comment: The problem was just with the second brackets outside. Those need to be replaced with third brackets